# Calculating new entries in array based on entries from another array in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have a question based an how to "call" a specific cell in an array, while looping over another array.
Assume, there is an array a:

```
    a = [[a1 a2 a3],[b1 b2 b3]]
```

and an array b:

```
    b = [[c1 c2] , [d1 d2]]
```

Now, I want to recalculate the values in array b, by using the information from array a. In detail, each value of array b has to be recalculated by multiplication with the integral of the gauss-function between the borders given in array a. but for the sake of simplicity, lets forget about the integral, and assume a simple calculation is necessary in the form of:

```
    c1 = c1 * (a2-a1) ; c2 = c2 * (a3 - a2) and so on,
```

with indices it might look like:

```
    b[i,j] = b[i,j] * (a[i, j+1] - a[i,j])
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much and best regards,
Marc

Comment: Do you mean `c[i,j] = b[i,j] * (a[i, j+1] - a[i,j])`?

Comment: The elements `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` in `a` are `a[0][0]`, `a[0][1]`, `a[0][2]`, and the elements `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` in `a` are `a[1][0]`, `a[1][1]`, `a[1][2]`. It's confusing that you have elements named `b` in the `a` array. Anyway, given that, you should be able to figure out what the indices are for the elements in your `b` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would split your a table in a table of lower bound and one of upper bound to work with aligned tables and improve readability :

```
lowerBounds = a[...,:-1]
upperBounds = a[...,1:]
```

Define the Gauss function you provided :

```
def f(x, gs_wdth = 1., mean=0.):
    return 1./numpy.sqrt(2*numpy.pi)*gs_wdth * numpy.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*gs_wdth**2))
```

Then, use a `nditer` (see [Iterating Over Arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/arrays.nditer.html)) to efficientely iterate over the arrays :

```
it = numpy.nditer([b, lowerBounds, upperBounds],
                   op_flags=[['readwrite'], ['readonly'], ['readonly']])
for _b, _lb, _ub in it:
    multiplier = scipy.integrate.quad(f, _lb, _ub)[0]
    _b[...] *= multiplier
print b
```

This does the job required in your post, and should be computationnaly efficient. Note that `b` in modified "in-place" : original values are lost but there is no memory overshoot during calculation.

Comment: I tried your version, with the line : multiplier = scipy.integrate.quad(f, _lb, _ub)  but unfortunately, he has a problem and makes the following call-out: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()  Where do I have to fill in any() or all() or does is even fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is scipy.integrate.quad is not vectorized and expects float arguments for lower and upper bounds. The solution is to provide elements of iterated arrays one at a time by removing the external_loop flag. I change my answer to reflect this. This should be less computationnaly efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function within a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [[k*(v[1]-v[0]) for k,v in zip(v,zip(s,s[1:]))] for s,v in zip(a,b)]
```

`zip(s,s[1:])` will gave you the desire pairs of elements that you want, for example :

```
>>> s =[4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(s,s[1:])
[(4, 5), (5, 6)]
```

Demo :

```
>>> b =[[7, 8], [6, 0]]
>>> a = [[1,5,3],[4 ,0 ,6]]
>>> [[k*(v[1]-v[0]) for k,v in zip(v,zip(s,s[1:]))] for s,v in zip(a,b)]
[[28, -16], [-24, 0]]
```

Comment: I think he wants `[[v[idx]*(j-i) for idx, (i,j) in enumerate(zip(s,s[1:]))] for s,v in zip(a,b)]`

Comment: @Alex yes,edited in same time with your reminding! ;)

Comment: Thank you both! I tried X = [[k*(scipy.integrate.quad(f, v[1], v[0])) for k,v in zip(v,zip(s,s[1:]))] for s,v in zip(a,b)] . I'm sure it works, but I need a special treatment for the function f.  I defined f = lambda x : 1/np.sqrt(2*pi)*gs_wdth) * np.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*gs_wdth**2)) The gaus-width is the same for each calculation above. The "mean" value changes for each "line" in the array a/b. For b = [[7,8],...]; a = [[1,5,3],...]  the gs_wdth is e.g. 2, for b = [...,[6,0]] ; a = [...,[4,0,6]] the gs_wdth is e.g. 4. The gs_wdth's are listed in an array e.g. wdt=[2,4].  Can this be included?

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this really cleanly with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a, b = np.array(a), np.array(b)
np.diff(a) * b
```